# what does reference pixel mean?

Tags: css, pixel, retina-display

What does "reference pixel" mean and what is the difference between it and the "hardware pixel"? Is it the "CSS pixel" or is that a different thing? How does the reference pixel enhance the web page views on smart phones?

Comment: How is this not a rehash of [your question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062505/reference-pixel-vs-hardware-pixel)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What does reference pixel mean**

The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

**What is the difference between it and hardware pixel**

The difference is between hardware pixels and CSS reference pixels reported by the browser.

**Is it the CSS pixel or the CSS pixel is a different thing**

Yes, CSS/reference/viewport pixels have the same mean

**How the reference pixel enhances the web pages views on smart phones**

This link will help you for this question:

http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/

http://www.siolon.com/blog/understanding-hardware-and-css-pixels/

Comment: can you explain the maths behind please `For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).`

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question

http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/

From what I can tell, its to do with the Pixel-Per-Degree, which takes into account both the screen resolution and the distance from which the device is viewed. This is the reference pixels.

"the hardware pixel relates to a physical element on a screen" - this I think is the something like the scrollbar on a browser or the pulldown menu on a mobile device

Comment: I have read it but still I am a little confused if you have an answer which is easier, I hope to answer me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Link-only answers are [considered to be bad on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). For example, links may become dead, and then nobody would know what the answer was about. Please cite the most relevant parts of the linked article.